# Proof a Rng cannot have exactly five non-zero divisors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, contest-math

Let $R$ be a Rng (a ring which does not necessarily have a $1$). We call an element $a$ regular if $xa=0$ implies $x=0$ and $ax=0$ implies $x=0$.

Prove $R$ cannot have exactly five regular elements.

This problem is from the Galois-Noether competition.

This is the progress so far. regular elements are closed under multiplication, their multiplications are cancellative. Therefore we can conceive the set $M$ of regular elements, if it had order $5$ then it would be a finite cancellative semigroup, hence a group. Since $5$ is prime it would have to be a cyclic group. Therefore $M$, with multiplication, would be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5$. I don't now if this is useful, but this is what I've found, I also have to thank Anon from chat for his help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $u$ be the unit in the group $M$ and let $S$ be the set of elements of $r\in R$ such that $ru=ur=r$.  Then $S$ is a subrng of $R$ and contains all of $M$, and in fact $S$ is a ring (with unit $u$).  Note furthermore that any unit of $S$ is in $M$, since $xy=yx=u\in M$ implies $x$ and $y$ are regular.  (Edit: In fact, $S$ is all of $R$; see anon's comment below.)

We thus are reduced to showing that no ring $S$ can have exactly $5$ units.  To show this, note that $-1$ is always a unit, but $\mathbb{Z}/5$ contains no nontrivial elements of order $2$, so we must have $1=-1$ in $S$.  Thus $S$ is an algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  We may also assume that $S$ is generated by its units (otherwise, just consider the subring they generate).  Thus we have that $S$ is isomorphic to some quotient of the group ring $\mathbb{F}_2[\mathbb{Z}/5]\cong \mathbb{F}_2\times \mathbb{F}_{16}$.  The only such quotients are $0$, $\mathbb{F}_2$, $\mathbb{F}_{16}$, and $\mathbb{F}_2\times\mathbb{F}_{16}$, none of which have exactly $5$ units.

Comment: If $u$ is the unit of $M$ then $u(ux-x)=0\Rightarrow ux=x$ and similarly $xu=x$ for all $x\in R$, so in fact $u$ would be a multiplicative identity for $R$. Then you can let $M=\langle a\rangle$, define a map $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^5-1)\to \Bbb F_2[a]$ and consider the number of units in its image (as you do)..

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Well, it happens to be true in this case, since no such $R$ actually exists.  But I agree that there is no clear way to prove it directly.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think we have to use that $S$ is all of $R$. Maybe I'm wrong but otherwise it would be conceivable for $S$ to have more than $5$ regular elements right? As a specific example $S$ could have $10$ regular elements in $S$, but $5$ regular elements in $R$ right? Also, isn't it possible that some of the regular elements of $S$ are not units? Thank you kindly.

Comment: @dREaM: It doesn't matter whether $S$ has regular elements that are not regular in $R$, or whether $S$ has regular elements that are not units.  I'm not saying anything about regular elements of $S$; I'm only talking about units of $S$.  Every unit in $S$ is a regular element of $R$; this follows from the more general fact that if there exist $y$ and $z$ such that $xy$ and $zx$ are regular, then $x$ is regular.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Thank you very much. Very nice solution.