# Cardinality of units in a commutative ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let A be a commutative ring with unity. A* denotes the group of units in A. Then cardinality of A* cant be

1. 5
2. 4
3. 3
4. 2

I know that there is a possibility of euler phi (n) elements in A*. So 2 &4 can be the cardinality of A*. But what about the other two options.

Comment: There is a finite field of order $4$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393557/proof-a-rng-cannot-have-exactly-five-non-zero-divisors